# System.NullReferenceException occurs

Tags: class, oop, initialization, windows-phone-8.1

I have to assign values to variables which are in `Question.cs`:

```
namespace Project.Classes.DataTypes
{
    public class Question_SubType
    {
        public int TotalNoOfAnswer { get; set; }
        public int TotalNoOfViews { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string PostedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public Question_SubType question { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool AskAsAnonymous { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my `MainPage.xaml.cs` I have code which gives me errors:

```
Question q1 = new Question();
q1.Email = "hello@hello.com"; //Works Fine
q1.question.QuestionId = 10;  //Gives Error
q1.question.Subject = "this is my question subject?";  //Gives Error
```

While degugging I observed that `AskAsAnonymous` is `null`, `Email` is `null`, but `question` is also `null`. So it gives me the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project.exe but was not handled in user code

What changes do I need to do in `Question.cs` or `MainPage.xaml.cs`?

Comment: You need to instantiate the `Question_SubType ` `question` in `Question`'s constructor

Comment: public Question()
        {
            Question_SubType questionObject;
        }

Comment: Tried using constructor. Doest work. Am i instantiating the right way?

Comment: Thats a declaration it will not create an instance, you need:  `public Question() { this.question = new Question_SubType(); }`